# 3D sphere tag cloud

Tags: 3d, tags, tag-cloud

Does anyone know how to achieve a 3D sphere tag cloud, like on this site:

http://krypted.com/

Is there a Javascript library that can easily do this, or was it most likely written by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is done in Flash using the WP-Cumulus plugin. While there are ways to accomplish it in javascript I haven't seen any ready-made products that do just that.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried to create simple "Sphere tag cloud" in JavaScript:

http://jstagsphere.sourceforge.net/

The main idea is to show how to create it - you can use it as is or improve in any way.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [TagCanvas](http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php) which draws to HTML5 canvas and is available either as stand alone JS or jQuery plugin.
Looks the same as the spherical example in flash and has options for other shapes too.

Comment: any modern alternative for TagCanvas?

Answer (score 2):

It's a wordpress plugin: [3D tag cloud](http://www.codedifferent.com/2009/01/12/gorgeous-3d-tag-cloud-plugin-for-wordpress-wp-cumulus/)
If you are putting it in a wordpress blog, you could just use that.
If you want to put it somewhere else, you could download that plugin and check out the source.

Answer (score 1):

I am creating another JavaScript 3D Tag-Cloud called rotator-js. It's working quite well. I try do optimize performance as much as possible.

https://github.com/ernesto-sun/rotator-js

At the readme-file at github you find more JS-3D-Tag-Spheres.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Very well done. +1 *Thanks also for the links to other 3D-tag-spheres. Most helpful.*

Answer (score 0):

You could write this in javascript using the canvas tag, but it would not work on IE, unless they fixed the problem with excanvas.js where you can now display text.

But, if you wanted it to work on FF3, Opera, Safari and Chrome then you can implement it, but it would have to be done by hand, as I don't know of any javascript library to do something like this.