# How to create rotating tag cloud in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I cannot explain the functionality actually. I want to rotate the links in spheric form. Visit this http://www.chemicalformula.org/. On this site, see the region "Chemical formulas" in middle-left of the page, where links are rotating in spheric, circular form. I want this functionality using jQuery / jQuery in ASP.net application. Can I achieve this ?

Comment: Right click on it, you will see its a flash plugin built by some website. Why not contact the site directly?

Comment: There are thousands of flash/javascript plugins that do this for you. Have you already looked yourself?

Comment: nice reply. thanks. but could not understand why -1?

Comment: He wanted it in jquery, which is javascript, not flash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [3D sphere tag cloud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501527/3d-sphere-tag-cloud)

Comment: Please read question carefully. I am not mentioned that can i achieve by flash. i want to use simple javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the Pseudo 3D you need to do some rotation matrix calculations.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

I can't answer the question whether or not **you** can achieve this . .

But I believe the code for this is available in many forms.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-sphere

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/cloud

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/how-to-create-a-3d-tag-cloud-in-jquery/

And many more . .

Answer (score 3):

What you have there in that website is the [**Cumulus Wordpress Plugin**](http://www.roytanck.com/2008/03/06/wordpress-plugin-wp-cumulus-flash-based-tag-cloud/) witch is free to use.

**There are several more that you can use**, you just need to provide text for the tags (could be other names) and the links for them.

Try Google from **Rotate Cloud Tag**

Also, if you want to have that **without any Flash**, you can see [this tutorial](http://www.gabrielpillet.com/en/blog/2/2010/08/22/creating-a-3d-cloud-tag-with-jquery-jquery-accessibility-php-seo-development-css) on how to do that using only jQuery. The Demo can be [found here](http://www.gabrielpillet.com/demos/en/tag-cloud/) as well.

Comment: Thanks this is also useful much for me