# 3d tag cloud asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tag-cloud

I want to create 3d tag cloud which pic the tags from the XML file. Any suggestion how can I do that?
It could be in Javascript, JQuery, flash or any other client side technology. But it should integrate with asp.net.
Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of the following:

JQuery: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/TagCloud.aspx
JQuery: http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/how-to-create-a-3d-tag-cloud-in-jquery/

ASP.Net MVC: http://www.wijix.com/post/Simple-Tag-Cloud-Implementation-for-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Silverlight: http://blog.petergerritsen.nl/2009/02/14/creating-a-3d-tagcloud-in-silverlight-part-1/

These use blog engine.net code - but you could examine the code!!

ASP.Net: http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/3d-tag-cloud-widget-for-blogenginenet-37051/

ASP.Net - Flash: http://www.ugochirico.com/post/2010/09/29/A-3D-Flash-Tab-Cloud-for-BlogEngineNET.aspx

Try these answers as well

[How to create rotating tag cloud in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038837/how-to-create-rotating-tag-cloud-in-jquery) and
[3D sphere tag cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501527/3d-sphere-tag-cloud)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in just plain JavaScript with images: [JS-Cumulus](http://jeroenvanwarmerdam.nl/content/resources/javascript/jscumulus/jscumulus.aspx) ([demo](http://jeroenvanwarmerdam.nl/content/resources/javascript/jscumulus/js-cumulus.html)).